# Laravel mysql select result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to add a feature to a website built with Laravel.
There is a table containing vote numbers and user. I want to get the total points a user has in a certain category. I do not have any PHP or Laravel experience but said I would give this a shot.

```
$votes1 = UserVotes::select ('select vote from user_votes where feedback_id = ? and feedback_type = 1',  Auth::user()->id);
```

This should return an object containing the vote amount. I want to interrogate the the object to check if the vote number is above a certain amount and then do something based on that being the case or not.

```
if vote > 50{
    //do stuff 
}

foreach ($votes1 as $vote1) {
     echo $vote1->vote;
}
```

The query should return 1. I have verified this by querying the database, so the problem is with my understanding of Laravel or php. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No error, just an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to construct your own SQL statement; Eloquent will do that for you.

If your models are set up in the default way, your query would look something like:

```
$votes = UserVotes::where('feedback_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('feedback_type', 1)
    ->get();
```

You can then iterate over that as normal.

Additionally, if there is a relationship set up with the user model you could do something like

```
$votes = Auth::user()->votes()
    ->where('feedback_type', 1)
    ->get();
```

Check out the documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Answer (score 2):

assuming UsersVotes extends Model,  here's how you should do it:

    `UsersVotes::select('vote')->where('feedback_type',  1)->where('feedback_id', Auth::user()->id)-get();`